# How to skip a line that causes an error while reading file?

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, file-handling

I want to read a file line-by-line such that I skip any lines that cause an error when reading that line.

For instance, if I have a file that contains the following text:

```
line 1
line 2
line ǵ
line 3
```

The character "ǵ" causes an error when Python tries to read the file line-by-line. I want to print all lines except "line ǵ" such that the output is like this:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

How should I do this?

I tried to read the file line-by-line using a while loop like so:

```
f = open('patients.txt', 'r')


while True:
    try:
        line = f.readline()
        print(line)
        if not line:
            break
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        print('Error reading line, skipping line')
        next(f)
```

However, the error causes the program to not even read any of the lines. I also used next(f) since without it the file iterator would be stuck on the line with the error. However, now I am also getting an error for reaching the end of the file where next(f) would cause an error.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best and most flexible way is for you to read all lines and just skip the ones, that include characters you don't want. You can easily do that using 're' (Regex) library. You can read all lines without error by using different encoding.

```
import re

with open('patients.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in f:
        if re.search('[^a-zA-Z0-9\n\t\s]', line):
            print('Special character found, skipping line')
            continue
        print(line.rstrip())
```